# How to set a 2 profit targets in pine script , one with 1:1 risk reward and 1:2.?

Tags: pine-script

How do I in pine script set a stop loss below a recent swing low and set 2 targets one of a 1:1 risk to reward ratio (rr) and a second target for the rest of the investment to 1:2 (rr). I cant seem to figure it out. Is there an example somewhere?
I get that if I get the swinglow, I can substract the buy price, but somehow it seems that I cant store the difference.
any help is much appreciated :) thanks

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)



shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)




var float swingLow = 0
var float recentSwinglow = 0
var float SL= 0 

var float TP1 = 0 
var float TP2 = 0 
var float difference = 0

swingLow := ta.lowest(low, 20)



longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)


    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)    
    recentSwinglow := swingLow
    // set 1 TP 1:1
    // use difference from swinglow and buy price and add that to the buy price that is the 1: 1 price
    SL := recentSwinglow
    
    difference := strategy.position_avg_price - recentSwinglow
    
    firstTakeProfit = strategy.position_avg_price + difference
    TP1 := firstTakeProfit
    TP2 := firstTakeProfit + difference
    
//shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))

//if shortCondition
//    strategy.entry('My Short Entry Id', strategy.short)

plot(recentSwinglow, color = color.red, linewidth = 2)
plotchar(recentSwinglow, title = "recentSwinglow")

plot(strategy.position_avg_price, color = color.white)
plotchar(strategy.position_avg_price, title = "price")

plotchar(difference, title = "difference")


plot(SL != 0? SL : na, color = color.red, linewidth = 2 )
plot(TP1 != 0? TP1 : na, color = color.green, linewidth = 2 )
plot(TP2 != 0? TP2 : na, color = color.purple, linewidth = 2 )
plotchar(TP1, title = "TP1")
plotchar(TP2, title = "TP2")



// idea from https://www.tradingview.com/script/kHhCik9f-Multiple-profit-exits-example/
strategy.exit('25%TP1', qty_percent=25, profit=TP1, loss=SL)
//strategy.exit("x2", qty_percent = 25, profit = percentAsPoints(2), loss = SL)
//strategy.exit("x3", qty_percent = 25, profit = percentAsPoints(3), loss = SL)
strategy.exit('TP2', profit=TP2, loss=TP1)

if (close < SL and  strategy.position_size > 0 )
    strategy.close('My Long Entry Id')
```